# Regex: How Do I Edit my Regex in order to Strip % Signs?

Tags: regex

I need some Regex help.

I've got a series of numbers. For example: `2010 95 34% 22 55%`

I use this Regex to put add quotation marks and commas:

```
([\d.]+%?)

'$1',
```

It works great. But, I need to strip the % sign. How do I edit the above Regex to do so?

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This RE: `([\d.]+)%?`
What language are you using?

Comment: Hi Lekensteyn, Thanks for the message. I'm using Dreamweaver as a text editor. And then sticking the data with quotation marks and commas added into a mySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
([\d.]+)%?
```

With the same replacement:

```
'$1',
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move the % outside the capturing group, so that it's not included in the value that's used for $1 in the replacement...

```
([\d.]+)%?
```